# How I force alt+tab on programs that don't allow it?

Tags: windows-8

Some windows software can block alt+tab, several games are offenders on this (usually because alt+tabbing breaks them in some way).

The thing is, I DO want to alt+tab anyway - how can I do that?

Comment: the thing is, if the game intercepts the alt-tab keypress before it gets to windows then you are never going to alt+tab anyway.

Comment: Can you just "ctrl alt del" then cancel in win8 still? Use a "hot corners" program where detection of your curser in the most upper left pixel would send out a Alt-Tab itself, bypassing an interception? Program it to a keyboard or mouse macro button thing, where a press is diverted through the input device special software?
Set a global key combo to fire up a program changing focus?  There must be other cheap tricks too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attempt to use other Windows shortcuts, provided that they aren't also disabled by the game in question. Such shortcuts are:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>  or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Brings up Start Menu/Start Screen )
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Shortcut for desktop )
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Shortcut to minimize all windows )
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (Shortcut to bring up Task Manager. Bringing up another window may force your fullscreen program to the background.)

Additionally, you can attempt to make a -windowed shortcut to the application.

You may find help in this question: [Force fullscreen games to in window mode?](https://superuser.com/questions/318748/force-fullscreen-games-to-in-window-mode)

If you can get the fullscreen game to run in windowed mode, you may be more successful in using Windows shortcuts, like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Comment: By the way, none of that really worked in one specific case, but it is mostly correct for most cases, so I will tag as correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's possible for the developer of the application to intentionally or unintentionally disable all of those options. In my experience, games that don't allow it are designed to handle the graphics in a way that allows game to not be in focus (especially for multi-platform games). I'm sorry this didn't help you in this case!

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this (worked for me on certain games):

Alt+Tab Without Holding Alt Down:
The Alt+Tab switcher normally closes when you release the Alt key. But, if you’d like to Alt+Tab without holding the Alt key down the whole time, you can. Press Alt+Ctrl+Tab, and then release all three keys. The Alt+Tab switcher will stay open on your screen.

You can use the Tab key, the arrow keys, or your mouse to select the window you want. Press Enter or the space bar to switch to your highlighted window.

Source for other options:
https://www.howtogeek.com/429223/master-windows-10s-alttab-switcher-with-these-tricks/